# How can I restore default window size in KVM/QEMU

Tags: kvm, qemu, window-management

In KVM/QEMU machine window size by default matches guest OS resolution. But if I resize windows (accidently) how to restore default size?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By pressing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-kvm

In the future, you can also try to use *man* (in a terminal).
This gives you the user manual. You can seek a word by pressing "/" (without the quotes) and then cycle through the references using "n":

```
man qemu
/restore <enter>
n
n
```

To quit, type "q".

Answer (score 0):

Assimunig you're talking about `virt-manager` or `virt-viewer`:

Click "View", select "Resize to VM"

Comment: I don't use _virt-*_. I have only qemu window and qemu console